# How can i get total value after add paid value in php

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have make a managment system in which i m making sales page. I make all the fields. Now after entering the items, I want the management system to show me total of all and when i add paid money it show me left amount from total. Html Code is below

```
       <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    
      <thead>
        
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Batch No</th>
        <th>Remarks</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Cost Per Piece</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </thead>
        

    <tbody id="tbody">
   

</tbody>
<center><button type="button" name=""  onclick="additem()" class="btn btn-success"> Add</button></center></td>

<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><h3 style="color:red;">Total Amount</td>
     <td><input type="number" id="totalamount" class="form-control" name="text" readonly /></td>
  
 

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td> </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><h3 style="color:red;">Paid</td>
     <td><input type="number" name="paid" id="total10" oninput="calculateTotal()" class="form-control" /></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td> </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><h3 style="color:red;">G.T.Balance</td>
     <td><input type="number" name=""  id="gtotal" class="form-control" readonly /></td>
  </tr> 

 
        </table>
```

Now the jquery code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
let x = 0;
function additem() {
x++;
  var html=`<tr;
      <td><center>${x}</center></td>
      <td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='product_name[]' required></td>
      <td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='batch_no[]' required></td>
      <td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='remarks[]' required></td>
      <td><input id='qty${x}' type='number' class='form-control' oninput='calculate(${x})' name='total_qty[]' required></td>
      <td><input id='cost${x}' type='number' class='form-control'  oninput='calculate(${x})'name='cost[]' required></td>
      <td><input type='number' class='form-control'   id='total${x}'  name='total[]' readonly required></td>
      <td><button type='button' id='btn' class='btn btn-danger'><i class='fa fa-remove'></i></button></td>
      </tr>`; 
      document.getElementById("tbody").insertRow().innerHTML= html;

}

function calculate(x) {
  const qty = document.getElementById(`qty${x}`).value;
  const cost = document.getElementById(`cost${x}`).value;
  const totalElem = document.getElementById(`total${x}`);
  totalElem.value = qty * cost
  calculateTotal()
}

function calculateTotal() {
  let fields = document.getElementsByName('total')
  let total = 0
  fields.forEach(f => {
    total = total + parseInt(f.value)
  })
  document.getElementById('totalamount').value = total
  let paid = document.getElementById('total10').value || 0 // If you change the  id of the "paid" field, change it here too.
  let subtotal = total - parseInt(paid)
  
  document.getElementById('gtotal').value = subtotal
}


  $(document).on('click',"#btn", function(e)
    {
      var r = $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      x=0;
    });


  
   
</script>
```

I have make a function name calculate total before it return me right value now it is returning me 0. Please kindly help me

Comment: Your structure `HTML` is all wrong, for example you open and close `<tbody>` and put `<td>` outside it, or you open `<tr>` without close it. Please start to fix it.

Comment: Sir the issue is in javascript function

Comment: I have posted an answer check it. It works, I have tested.

Comment: Start to fix your HTML into HTML and into JS (example: `var html=<tr;`, why you close `<tr>` with `;` ????)

Answer (score -1):

Changes in var html variable:
From:  name='total[]'

To: name='total'

Note: You must not be mixing JS and HTML together. There are also issues with your HTML table.

```js
var html=`<tr>
          <td><center>${x}</center></td>
          <td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='product_name[]' required></td>
          <td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='batch_no[]' required></td>
          <td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='remarks[]' required></td>
          <td><input id='qty${x}' type='number' class='form-control' oninput='calculate(${x})' name='total_qty[]' required></td>
          <td><input id='cost${x}' type='number' class='form-control'  oninput='calculate(${x})'name='cost[]' required></td>
          <td><input type='number' class='form-control'   id='total${x}'  name='total' readonly required></td>
          <td><button type='button' id='btn' class='btn btn-danger'><i class='fa fa-remove'></i></button></td>
          </tr>`;
```